# How do rankings in competitive table tennis work?

Tags: table-tennis, ranking

I've often heard of 2000 rank or 1250 rank in competitive table tennis. What does this mean? How far do ranks go? How do you attain a rank? I live in the USA so the governing body is the USATT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USATT (United States Association of Table Tennis) has a ranking system for all members of the USATT.  It's a point based system.

Put simply, points are gained by defeating other ranked players in USATT sanctioned tournaments, and lost when defeated by ranked players.  Some of the highest ranking players in America usually end up in the 2700-2900 range.  1800-2200 points is pretty common for intermediate level competitive players.

In order to get a ranking, you simply need to sign up for the USATT through their website and play in your first tournament. More information on tournaments, including a list of national tournaments, and rankings can be found on the USATT website.

Answer (score 3):

USA ranking is managed by USATT using some simplified Elo [rating system](http://www.teamusa.org/USA-Table-Tennis/Ratings/How-Does-the-USATT-Rating-System-work).

Rating system transforms performances into a score, where higher value means better player. Most famous is aformentioned [**Elo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) (here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison) between most known).

If you're interested in use, in addition to the theory, you should give a try to [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system, that can manage small to large playing groups, and it features rankings, stats, and more. We host many [table tennis groups/clubs](https://rankade.com/dojo).